# How to Read httpservletresponse inside Spring interceptor?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, filter, interceptor

I'm working on task that log api request and response in database. I need to autowire spring beans to access database and we can not autowire spring beans inside filter.

Problem is we can read response multiple times only in filter using HttpServletResponseWrapper.

> Is there any way to read response multiple times in spring interceptor?

Here is my code using **Filter**. It can retrieve all information but can't autowire beans in ApiActivityManager to insert data in database.

If I read response in Interceptor once then in controller response is null.

```
public class ApiActivityInterceptor implements Filter {
    ApiActivityManager apiActivityManager = new ApiActivityManager();

    @Override public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    }

    @Override 
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        MyRequestWrapper requestWrapper = new MyRequestWrapper((HttpServletRequest)request);
        MyResponseWrapper responseWrapper = new MyResponseWrapper((HttpServletResponse)response);
        InputStream inputStream = requestWrapper.getInputStream();
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
        if (inputStream != null) {
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            char[] charBuffer = new char[128];
            int bytesRead = -1;
            while ((bytesRead = bufferedReader.read(charBuffer)) > 0) {
                stringBuilder.append(charBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
        } else {
            stringBuilder.append("");
        }
        String requestText = stringBuilder.toString();
        log.info(requestText);

        chain.doFilter((ServletRequest)requestWrapper,(ServletResponse)responseWrapper);

        String responseText = new String(responseWrapper.getCopy(),responseWrapper.getCharacterEncoding());
        log.info(responseText);
        //for log details in database
        activityLogDetails.setActivityLog(requestText,responseText);
    }

    @Override public void destroy() {

    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You **can** autowire beans for filters. You have to use `DelegatingFilterProxy`.

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I am facing this same issue.

Comment: @n3o , I had been solved it already. I will post answer today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To autowire spring beans in the filter class,

1. first add `@Component` annotation in your filter class.
2. Register filter with filter name as bean name and filter class as org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy

So my solution is looks like,

**ApiActivityFilter.java**

```
@Component("apiActivityFilter")
public class ApiActivityFilter implements Filter {

    @Autowired
    ApiActivityManager apiActivityManager;

    @Override public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    }

    @Override 
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        MyRequestWrapper requestWrapper = new MyRequestWrapper((HttpServletRequest)request);
        MyResponseWrapper responseWrapper = new MyResponseWrapper((HttpServletResponse)response);
        InputStream inputStream = requestWrapper.getInputStream();
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
        if (inputStream != null) {
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            char[] charBuffer = new char[128];
            int bytesRead = -1;
            while ((bytesRead = bufferedReader.read(charBuffer)) > 0) {
                stringBuilder.append(charBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
        } else {
            stringBuilder.append("");
        }
        String requestText = stringBuilder.toString();
        log.info(requestText);

        chain.doFilter((ServletRequest)requestWrapper,(ServletResponse)responseWrapper);

        String responseText = new String(responseWrapper.getCopy(),responseWrapper.getCharacterEncoding());
        log.info(responseText);
        //for log details in database
        apiActivityManager.logApiActivity(activityLog);//activityLog Object to be logged
    }

    @Override public void destroy() {

    }
}
```

Register filter using **Java config**

```
FilterRegistration.Dynamic apiActivityFilter = servletContext.addFilter("apiActivityFilter", DelegatingFilterProxy.class);
apiActivityFilter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, true, "/api/*");
```

Register filter using **XML config**

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>apiActivityFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>apiActivityFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```